# Openpyxl change excel cell color

Tags: python, excel, colors, openpyxl

I get some problem when I try to use openpyxl

here comes my code

I have no idea why it didn't working

```
import openpyxl 
from openpyxl.styles import PatternFill

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook("123.xlsx")
ws = wb.active #Name of the working sheet

fill_cell1 = PatternFill(patternType='solid', fgColor='FC2C03')
fill_cell2 = PatternFill(patternType='solid', fgColor='03FCF4') 
fill_cell3 = PatternFill(patternType='solid', fgColor='35FC03') 
fill_cell4 = PatternFill(fgColor='FCBA03')  

ws['B2'].fill = fill_cell1
ws['B3'].fill = fill_cell2
ws['B4'].fill = fill_cell3
ws['B5'].fill = fill_cell4

wb.save("123.xlsx")
```

[the output just like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RD2pD.png)

Comment: Could you please show us what ouput you are getting now and what output do you expect?

Comment: However it seems to work well on my PC.

Comment: it about office 365? whats your excel version?

Comment: Actually I'm using Office 2021 LTSC.

Comment: I suppose you to do some other operations on `123.xlsx` to ensure you are really operaing on the file you expect.

Comment: hey guys its about excel problem, if you use office 365 the color will still change but can not be seen. I ask my friend for help who use office 2019, he can see the color change

Comment: Tried in o365 and it works. Python 3.8.8 and openpyxl 3.0.7. Please check to see you have a recent version of the same. FYI - B5 did not change, background color of rest has changed